# Get user profile from Given name Flow

Tags: office-365, flow

I was reading some forums where all the answers says that the UPN is something as `jon_doe@example.com` but all I have its a name ie `Jon Doe`. I'm trying to get the email using a name, but I don't seem to do it correctly or I don't know if this is even possible right now. I'm trying to do this because the flow currently puts the Name value directly into the field but when there are two or more options for the same person (ie the person has two accounts, one for admin rights and one normal) gives an error, using the email will get rid of this error since email is a unique value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you could search by **Last Name** using **[Search for user (V2)]** and then apply filter on **[Given name]**. If multiple records still exist after the first filter, need to apply filter again on a different field.

[image]

```
body('Filter_array')?[1]['Mail']
```